# Setup Q-municate Chat application

Tags: android, chat

I have downloaded Quickblox Q-municate from the github,

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android

and trying to import it into eclipse ide using,

Go to menu File - New - Project. Select Android Project from Existing Code and Browse to your project-directory, click Finish.

But it says two main activities and not able to import all projects. Without selecting one main it proceeds but the project is not building. I have checked their help but not able to find any details about it.

Can anybody tell me the steps to import and run the project in eclipse ide?

Thanks